# What role do I need to be able to run get_ddl(object_type, object_name) on a snowflake secure view?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with Snowflake, and need to give someone the ability to run "get_ddl()" on a secure view.  What role do they need to do this?

In other words, some roles should not see the DDL behind the view, others should.  How do I enable this difference in access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-secure.html#interacting-with-secure-views

Per this document, only the owning role of a secure view may run a get_ddl() function.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake is a role-based data access system, not a user-based one (unlike some other databases).

For users who need access to the secure view DDL definition, grant the view owning role to these users (this assumes the best practice has been followed that the secure view was created by a custom role that's been created to create and manage such database objects and not created by system built-in roles like sysadmin).

Users who have not been granted the view owning role will not be able to access the secure view definition, so achieving the difference in access privilege.